How to handle time synchronization between 2 systems?
I have 2 systems, in which system A sends time in UTC to system B.
System B converts it to local time, sets it using the Windows API, and then returns back the local time and timezone bios to system A. If the returned result does not match, System A retries.
time_t dateTime = X; //UTC time from System A 
struct tm newDateTime;
_tzset();
localtime_s(&newDateTime, &dateTime);  
SYSTEMTIME walltime; // Below values are filled from newDateTime, Below is example when issue comes. 
walltime.wYear = 2024; 
walltime.wMonth = 11;
walltime.wDay = 3; 
walltime.wHour = 01; 
walltime.wMinute = 59; 
walltime.wSecond = 30; 
if (!SetLocalTime(&walltime)) { 
    // ERROR handling       
} 
//After setting the time 
DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION timeZoneInformation = { 0 };
DWORD result = GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation(&timeZoneInformation);
int bias = (result == TIME_ZONE_ID_DAYLIGHT)     ? (timeZoneInformation.Bias + timeZoneInformation.DaylightBias) : (timeZoneInformation.Bias + timeZoneInformation.StandardBias) 
std::cout << "Calculated Bias: " << bias << std::endl;

For the above scenario, if the timezone is central time (-6:00),
I want to get the calculated bios as -300 or -360 based on whether DST is applicable or lifted, irrespective of time correction happening.
The above code works in all the scenarios except for the ambiguous time period of 1AM-2AM, in which it should return a value based on whether DST is lifted.
Can anyone help me in how to handle this scenario?

Converting to local time is lossy. Once you've converted to local time there is nothing you can do to recover the information pertaining to daylight savings. Don't trash your data and you won't be in a situation to have to solve a problem that has no solution.

Date and time is always harder than people expect it to be. Find and use a library to handle all your date, time and timezone calculations.

Avoid local time in all scenarios besides showing it as text for human reading. Local time is calculated based on narrowly local political decisions.

Use SetSystemTime() which uses UTC. Also, do error handling on GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation(), and use GetTimeZoneInformation() as a fallback

@RemyLebeau I tried using setsytemtime time, when used to change time in dst the fallback is not happening.

Now I understand how messy time handling is . Unfortunately I have to deal with it

@soumyasambitKunda by "fallback",  I was referring to calling GetTimeZoneInformation() if GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation() fails, which you are not checking for. What is the actual problem you are having? Please [edit] your question to provide more specific details.
